# android sqlite subquery for getting filtered data

Tags: android, sqlite

How can I execute a subquery in an SQLite database for Android using the rawquery function to retreive the data from the database.

I want to execute query like below:

```
select * from table1 where id not in (select id from table2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to get a readable instance of your database using `getReadableDatabase()` invoked on [SQLiteOpenHelper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html) class and this way you will be returned a [SQLiteDatabase](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html) object. You can invoke `rawQuery()` on it like:

```
String rawQuery = "select * from table1 where id not in (select id from table2)";
Cursor tCursor = yourSQLiteDBObject.rawQuery(rawQuery, null);
```

Comment: NOTE: You MUST return a field named `_id` when working with Cursors otherwise the query attempt will fail. If 'table1' (for example) doesn't contain a column explicitly named `_id` then you must alias it, e.g., `SELECT id AS _id ...`

Comment: Yes, I completely agree with the what @MisterSqounk said.